Не добавляется Jwt токен в куки с Asp.Net Core - HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("uft-cookies", token);
У меня есть сервер Asp.Net Core Web Api, на нём с помощью контроллера я отдаю клиенту(Blazor) токен и записываю его сразу в куки:
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("uft-cookies", token);

return Ok(token);

В program.cs сервера я добавил Cors:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowWebOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7238")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

И политику куки:
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
    HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
});

Запрос сам выполняется, токен передаётся пользователю, но почему-то не записывается ему в куки, хотя вроде все запросы выполнены:
Я смотрел в Network - в куки пусто. Если кто знает решение, напишите
EDIT:
Я решил эту проблему, путём перехода на Blazor Web Assembly. Но теперь появилась другая проблема. Браузер просто отклоняет куки в заголовке Set-Cookie. То есть я вижу добавление этих кук в браузере, но в самом контейнере они не появляются.
